# Flutter - invoke function inside widget builder

Tags: flutter

I'm writing code like this:

- I wrote a common widget item for ListView: `ItemBuilder`.
- When the item is clicked, it will call the callback `onClickItem` for the parent can handle stuff: `doSomeThingFirst`
- After `doSomeThingFirst` has done, I want `doSomethingSecond` on `ItemBuilder` can be invoked.

```dart
class ListItemWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  ...
  Widget listDataWidget() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = listData[index];
            return ItemBuilder(onClickItem: () {
              doSomeThingFirst();
            });
        }
    );
  }

  void doSomeThingFirst() {

  }

}


class ItemBuilder {

  final Function? onClickItem;

  ItemFileWidget({this.onClickItem});

  Widget build() {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          onClickItem?.call();
        },
        child: Container()
      );
  }

  void doSomethingSecond() {
    
  }


}
```

Could you guys please give some idea about this?

Comment: How about using `async`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh how to apply `async` to this? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a call to `doSomethingSecond()` after `onClickItem?.call()`

Comment: It can't. I want to perform `doSomethingSecond` after `doSomeThingFirst` has done.

Comment: You can make `doSomeThingFirst()` `async` and 

`return ItemBuilder(onClickItem: () async { await   doSomeThingFirst();});`

Now `doSomeThingFirst()` will first `await` to be completed, then `doSomethingSecond()` can be invoked as I proposed.

Comment: thank you for your comment. But I changed the solution.